# How to ask Ambari service to start automatically

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I'm implementing the Ambari service and need to have it started aotumatically after cluster was started. Is there some option in metainfo.xml to enable this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking how to ensure ambari-server starts up on boot? Or are you asking how to ensure all services in an ambari cluster start on cluster boot?

Comment: I'm asking how to force autostart for my custom service. Ambari-server itself starts and it starts also all services preinstalled in sandbox. But how to implement the same feature for my custom service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure auto restart for the services through ambari:
[image]

Also, if you want Ambari to auto restart you can add it as a service and demonize the service, so that it will restart automatically.

Comment: Probably you have newer Ambari version because there is no autostart option in mine